# Window Animation Possibility?

Tags: wpf, animation, window

I am wondering if it is possible to have a WPF window animated in the way shown in the gif below

[image: gif]

Comment: Doesn't the `Popup` class do just that?

Comment: WPF has a Popup class? (you think it can do the job for me?)

Comment: Is the blue background your desktop, i.e. is your window transparent?

Comment: desktop,by the way the app is klipfolio.com

Comment: I'm only looking for how the window is animated that way... and can it be done in WPF....

Answer (score 0):

Try using a popup and animate on mouseover event with storyboards.